# Screen 1 completely black after unlocking the machine

Tags: windows, display, multiple-monitors, external-display, graphics

Windows 10 machine, connected to an external screen with HDMI.

Before leaving the computer one tends to lock the screen (Windows Key + L).

Then when one comes back after a period of time and adds the password, the screen 1 is completely black.

In the Display Settings if one selects "Extend these displays", it then reverts back to "Show only 2".

[image]

I thought that it had to do with the power settings. So went to `Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Power Options\Edit Plan Settings`

However, just for a sanity check, pressed "Change advanced power settings".

In the Power Options, more specifically in the Sleep section, in the Hibernate, I had a time in both "On battery" and "Plugged in", and changed to Never.

[image]

I thought that with this last part, the problem would be solved, but that was not the case.

On another hand, I've tried unplugging the HDMI cable but the screen 1 is still black.

Restarting the machine solves the problem, but one doesn't want to do that every time this happens.

Any idea on what it is and how to solve it?

---

**Edit**

Updated the Intel drivers, but the problem persists.

In order to do that, went to [this site](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/detect.html) to download Intel® Driver & Support Assistant (Intel® DSA).

Once that installation was completed, opened the software and that redirected to the following website: https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/intel-driver-support-assistant.html

From here one can see that there are three updates.

[image]

Downloaded and installed all of them (after installing one it will ask if you want to reboot so you may want to reboot only when all are installed)

[image]

In order to install Intel Killer Performance Suite I had to remove the two Killer software that I had installed, as I was always getting the following error

> Killer Performance Driver Suite UWD cannot be installed with Killer
> Ethernet Performance Suite.

Now all the drivers are up to date

[image]

But the issue still persists.

Comment: Set primary display as 1 _(if it's already set, change primary to external monitor, the back to primary display)_ and reboot to see if this resolves. Does this occur with the external monitor detached?

Comment: @JW0914 Primary device (laptop's screen) is set as Display 1. As for the question, if Display 1 is completely black and one removes the HDMI, the screen stays black. If one connects the HDMI, one can see the Display 2.

Comment: Did you try my first sentence, as this is often the issue when occurring with an external display connected? While the primary display should always remain primary, sometimes there's an issue with how this is executed within the OS - normally, the external display should stay black until the primary is awake with a video signal, and since it's the inverse, this seems to be the issue.

Comment: @JW0914 in the Display Settings (when one right clicks on one's desktop), I've noticed that for Display 1 the `Make this my main display` was unticked. Already ticked it - this may very well solve the issue. Will update you in a while.

Comment: On another hand, accessed NVIDIA Control Panel, and in `Display`>`Set up multiple displays`, more specifically in point 2 (Drag the icons to match your display configuration) I can only see screen 1. If I right click and press `Identify`, the number one appears in both Display 1, and Display 2.

Comment: @JW0914 the problem was not solved. When I ticked the `Make this my main display` Desktop's icons got really messy, as they were on Screen 2. After unlocking the computer, the Display 1 turns black, and Display 2 is the only one with image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the ideal solution, as would be nice to save some energy by allowing the screen to go off, but ended up preventing the display to turn off. This way when the machine is unlocked both screens are working.